# Which visa type for PhD in Germany?

Tags: germany, study

I've received a PhD scholarship offer from a German Professor
with a fixed stipend value of 1200 Euro/month for the period of 1 year,
which will either convert into 75 % of TVF-13, or will continue the same stipend.

So, now the major confusion in my mind is what type of visa I should apply for. Should I apply for a student visa, a work visa, or some other type of visa?

I am from Pakistan.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to apply for a German type D (National Schengen long stay visa) study visa.
See the [relevant page of the German embassy to Pakistan](http://www.pakistan.diplo.de/Vertretung/pakistan/en/06Legal/2__visa__longterm/2__Study__visa__Seite.html).

For an overview of the process, I found a very informative [sheet of the DAAD](http://m.india.diplo.de/contentblob/3651966/Daten/2650842/DAAD_Studying_in_Germany_PhD_DD.pdf) (German Academic Exchange Service) for India (so be aware that some details may be different, e.g. required documents, waiting times for visa) that explains also the academic environment for a PhD in Germany.

Finally I would also advise you to get in touch with the international office of your prospective university.